# How do you export a file SQLite db using Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, sqlite, import

I'm Dalsam from Korean. 24old

I'm using Eclipse java tools, and develop android.

I have question.

This query is successed.

```
SQLite>.mode list     
SQLite>.separator ","     
SQLite>.output WordDB.csv    
SQLite>selete * from WordDB;     
SQLite>.exit
```

As result, the file 'WordDB.csv' will be created. In Eclipse, but this command does not run.

```
class WordDBManager extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
...
}

WordDBManager mgr = new WordDBManager();    
String sql = ".mode list";    
mgr.getWritableDatabase().execSQL(sql);    
sql = ".separator \",\"";    
mgr.getWritableDatabase().execSQL(sql);    
sql = ".output WordDB.csv";    
mgr.getWritableDatabase().execSQL(sql);    
sql = selete * from WordDB;    
mgr.getWritableDatabase().execSQL(sql);    
sql = ".exit";


<Error message>
02-23 05:16:40.095: I/Database(27383): sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = near ".": 

syntax error    
02-23 05:16:40.095: E/Database(27383): Failure 1 (near ".": syntax error) on 0x30d3a0 when 

preparing '.mode list'.
```

What should I do?

Comment: I don't have an answer, but can I just say...I'm lovin the sentimental touch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"." (dot) commands are not part of the SQL language but control commands for the sqlite interpreter, that's why you are receiving syntax errors trying to interpret them as SQL.

You can find the available SQL syntax at http://www.sqlite.org/syntaxdiagrams.html.

Answer (score 0):

window->Perspective->open perspective ->Other ->DDMS 
-then Search for your project on the left side 
-choose file explorer from the right 
-search for file data then data again 
-search for your project name again 
-then database open it you will find your database
*if you want to import it choose your database then you will find button on top there is a title on it called pull a file from the device you can open it by firefox plugin called SQLite Manager.